# numprint and similar packages ignore ADF Fonts

Tags: tables, fonts, numprint

I'm using the Venturis font for my documents. Because all of tabular number alignment packages I tried interfere with fonts, numbers in these columns look quite out of place.

Is there a way around this?

Here's an example that illustrates this issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[np]{numprint}

\usepackage[lf]{venturis} %% lf option gives lining figures as default;
              %% remove option to get oldstyle figures as default

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{n{7}{2}|r}
  {Some Data} & Some Data \\
  \hline
    100000   &  \np{100000} \\
      230    &  \np{230} \\
      111    &  \np{111} \\
      300.03 &  \np{300.03} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `n` columns use math mode and the `venturis` package doesn't change the math fonts. To the contrary, `\np` uses text mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `n`-type column uses math mode: you want a *text* font so need an `N`-type column (manual, page 10)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[np]{numprint}

\usepackage[lf]{venturis} %% lf option gives lining figures as default;
              %% remove option to get oldstyle figures as default

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{N{7}{2}|r}
  {Some Data} & Some Data \\
  \hline
    100000   &  \np{100000} \\
      230    &  \np{230} \\
      111    &  \np{111} \\
      300.03 &  \np{300.03} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the manual, I'd gotten the impression that N was for aligning exponents. Apparently I was wrong. Thanks!